# Double integration:$ \int_0^a \int_0^b e^{max(b^2x^2,a^2y^2)}dydx $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I would be grateful for a little help if someone could help me solve a problem in my textbook.

The question is, evaluate $ \int_0^a  \int_0^b e^{max(b^2x^2,a^2y^2)}dydx  $, where $a,b$ are positive numbers and $max(b^2x^2,a^2y^2)=b^2x^2$ if $b^2x^2 \geq a^2y^2$ and $a^2y^2$ if $b^2x^2 < a^2y^2$.

I've studied double integrals, but I'm not sure how to solve this question. I've looked at the answer sheet, and it says $\int_0^a  \int_0^{bx/a} e^{b^2x^2}dydx + \int_0^b  \int_0^{ay/b} e^{a^2y^2}dxdy$ but I don't really understand the meaning of this. Could someone lend me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your domain of integration separates along the curve 
$$
a^2 y^2 = b^2 x^2 \iff
y = \pm \frac{b}{a} x
$$

That looks like cutting the plane into four parts.
Considering only what happens within $[0,a] \times [0,b]$ is
$$
y = \frac{b}{a} x \quad (*)
$$
so $[0,a] \times [0,b]$ is split into two triangles along $(*)$.

For example $a = b = 1$ would cut $[0, a] \times [0, b]$ into two triangles along the diagonal $y = x$.

In each triangle only one case of the maximum selection applies, so you know what to integrate.

The rest is setting up the double integration on each triangle correctly,
and summing up both values. That is consistent with the answer from your sheet.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can break up the integral using, for $0 < a, b$,
$$
\max(b^{2}x^{2}, a^{2}y^{2})
  = \begin{cases}
    b^{2}x^{2} & \text{if $ay \leq bx$, i.e., $y \leq bx/a$,} \\
    a^{2}y^{2} & \text{if $bx \leq ay$, i.e., $x \leq ay/b$.}
\end{cases}
$$